# Making Vista style apps in C# for windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `Windows XP` and currently, I'm developing a small win form application so I want to give `Vista` or `Windows 7` appearances to my application which is running in `Windows XP` and I'm using `c#` to develop win form application.

Is it possible to do that?

If so then please let me know the way.

Comment: So you need some componentes. For ex Developer Express Win Forms can give what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With WPF you can. See http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/03/Forcing-WPF-to-use-a-specific-Windows-theme.aspx for more information.